# Async stream enrichment with a message queue (e.g. Kafka)

Tags: stream-processing, apache-kafka

I would like to enrich some streaming data, with one service per enrichment, possibly each service written in a different language and managed/deployed separately.

Each service would consume some Kafka topic, enrich the message, and publish it in some Kafka topic.

In the end, I would have a topic of fully enriched messages.

Ideally, some of the steps would be done concurrently, but this is not a requirement.

What are frameworks, protocols, or patterns matching this kind of use cases ? To me it looks like regular async micro services, but with high risk of coupling between the services.

Comment: Where does the data come from, going through a pipeline and where does it ends up?

Comment: Did you check out Kafka Streams? It is part of Kafka 0.10+ and a good fit to build micro services that read from and write to Kafka brokers, as you describe it in you question. Check out http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html and http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#streams and https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.1.x/kafka-streams

Comment: @rebeling data comes from the message queue and goes to the message queue :)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: Things like Kafka Stream, Samza, etc would not be meet the "each service written in a different language and managed/deployed separately" requirement :) I'm actually looking for good practices or feedbacks on this kind of setup

Comment: For different languages, you are right -- even if Kafka Streams might be available in other languages at some point (but that might take a while...). But Kafka Streams applications can be managed/deployed completely decoupled from each other... Fur multi-language stream processing, there is Concord (http://concord.io/), but it's not open source as far as I know.

Comment: What about Thrift https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift ?